# How do I make jQuery work if it exists but doesn't work?

Tags: jquery

I have troubles with jQuery, here's my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="example">a</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $('p').text('Jquery!');
    });
</script>
<script>
    if(window.jQuery!=null){
        alert("not null")
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use script's res="link" attribute and tried to download different versions of jQuery. Alert window  pops up, but nothing in jQuery script works at all...

Comment: POORLY PHRASED QUESTION:  "How do I make jQuery work if it exists but doesn't work?"  jQuery should always "work" ... provided you're USING it correctly :)  Q: Please tell us exactly what "isn't working", and please show us the corresponding line(s) of code that aren't giving you the expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codes inside `script` tag with `src` will not be executed. You need to put `src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"` inside a separate `<script>` tag before the one you are using to change the text inside `<p></p>` tag.
Code in your question is revised below:

```
<p id="example">a</p>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('p').text('Jquery!');
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        if (window.jQuery != null) {
            //alert("not null")
            console.log("not null");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Adding a simple explanation of what you changed and why would complete this answer. Code only answers are not very helpful if people have to do a code diff between original and answer

Comment: I had posted only the code in the answer based on my comment. However, reading it again I realised the point in your comment. Have updated the answer now.... Thanks

Comment: A quick explanation that a script tag can't have both an src and text code would help too, noting that the text code gets ignored when src exists

Comment: @Alwaysa Learner - Good catch!  I was baffled as to what the OP was trying to ask; I didn't notice that they were trying to run JS inside of the tag "<script src...>".  Thank you for updating your post with the explanation, too!  Hopefully the OP will "upvote" and "accept" your response..